# Debian 10: how to make faillog count

Tags: debian, pam

I have faillog installed by default and there is also /var/log/faillog.
But the file is always empty.

As far I found out I need to adjust some pam-files in /etc to enable it.

I read about pam_tally, pam_tally2, auth_common, system-auth, ...

So I think they are more or less do all the same but the files are different regarding the Linux distribution and version.

Can anyone tell me what to set exactly for Debian 10?

I do not want do lock/block users. I only want the failed-login counted.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `/var/log/auth.log`? Might also suit your needs.

Comment: Yes but then I need to cout myself and handle old logs. I think the internal counting of faillog would do that for myself - until I do the counter-reset.

Comment: Seems to be a long-standing bug in Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=776314

Comment: There's a patch (https://sources.debian.org/patches/shadow/1:4.2-3+deb8u4/429_login_FAILLOG_ENAB/) that went in 4.8.1-1, which is in debian TESTING since 2020-02-13. But given it's not lintian clean, I don't think it's going anywhere soon. https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/shadow